# Move rows in dataframe according to time

Tags: python, pandas

```
dic = {'Employee ID':emp_id, 'Log Date':emp_logdate, 'Log Time':emp_logtime}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic).groupby(['Employee ID','Log Date']).agg({'Log Date':'first', 'Log Time': lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique())})['Log Time'].astype(str).str.split(', ', expand=True).reset_index()
```

Let's say I have a time log like this as the result on the code above:

```
'7:20',  '11:50', '12:49', '17:20'
'7:02',  '11:36', '12:59'   
'11:33', '12:40', '17:06'   
'11:38'
```

Given the above df, I want to move the row to their specific log sequence, like all 11 am logs are moved to the second column, all 12nn logs are moved to the third column, and all 5 pm logs are on the last column:

```
AM In   AM Out   PM In    PM Out
'7:20', '11:50', '12:49', '17:20'
'7:02', '11:36', '12:59', ' '
' ',    '11:33', '12:40', '17:06'   
' ',    '11:38', ' ',     ' '
```

Comment: What did you try so far and where are you stuck?

Comment: This is my code for my df, the first given df on my wuestion is the output of this:

dic = {'Employee ID':emp_id, 'Log Date':emp_logdate, 'Log Time':emp_logtime}
        df = pd.DataFrame(dic).groupby(['Employee ID','Log Date']).agg({'Log Date':'first', 'Log Time': lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique())})['Log Time'].astype(str).str.split(', ', expand=True).reset_index()

Comment: Thank you for providing code. please update your tried code in question.

Comment: please provide the definition of `emp_id`, `emp_log_date`, `emp_logtime` directly in the question

Answer (score 1):

One approach could be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

data = {0: {0: '7:20', 1: '7:02', 2: '11:33', 3: '11:38'}, 
        1: {0: '11:50', 1: '11:36', 2:  '12:40', 3: np.nan}, 
        2: {0: '12:49', 1: '12:59'   , 2: '17:06', 3: np.nan}, 
        3: {0: '17:20', 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan, 3: np.nan}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

d = {'AM_In': 7, 
     'AM_Out': 11, 
     'PM_In': 12, 
     'PM_Out': 17}

patt = re.compile('|'.join([f'(?P<{k}>{v}:.*)' for k,v in d.items()]))

res = df.stack().str.extractall(patt)
res = res.groupby(level=0).first()

print(res)

  AM_In AM_Out  PM_In PM_Out
0  7:20  11:50  12:49  17:20
1  7:02  11:36  12:59   None
2  None  11:33  12:40  17:06
3  None  11:38   None   None
```

You can turn those strings into proper time values as follows:

```
res = res.apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x).dt.time)

print(res)

      AM_In    AM_Out     PM_In    PM_Out
0  07:20:00  11:50:00  12:49:00  17:20:00
1  07:02:00  11:36:00  12:59:00       NaT
2       NaT  11:33:00  12:40:00  17:06:00
3       NaT  11:38:00       NaT       NaT
```

Explanation steps:

- First create a `dict` with the relevant key-value pairs: e.g. `'AM_In'` and `7`. N.B. make sure that the keys contain *only* alphanumeric characters. Regex placeholders do not allow spaces (see next step).
- Use a list comprehension to create the regex patterns with placeholders (generic: `(?P<name>...)`) by looping through [`d.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques). E.g. we get `(?P<AM_In>7:.*)`, which means: a group named 'AM_In', which captures '7' followed by ':' and everything after that.
- Use [`'|'.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join these patterns as *alternatives*. The result is `'(?P<AM_In>7:.*)|(?P<AM_Out>11:.*)|(?P<PM_In>12:.*)|(?P<PM_Out>17:.*)'` which we pass to [`re.compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.compile).
- For the next step we want to turn our `df` into a `pd.Series`. We use [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for this, and apply [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) to get all the captured groups in a new `pd.DataFrame`.
- At this stage, our `res` initially looks like this:

```
print(df.stack().str.extractall(patt).head())

          AM_In AM_Out  PM_In PM_Out
    match                           
0 0 0      7:20    NaN    NaN    NaN
  1 0       NaN  11:50    NaN    NaN
  2 0       NaN    NaN  12:49    NaN
  3 0       NaN    NaN    NaN  17:20
1 0 0      7:02    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

We are now nearly there:

- Next, we apply [`df.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on the *first level* of the index (so: `0`), and ask to get only `first()`, i.e. the first non-`NaN` value if available for each index value in each column. This will turn all duplicate index values into one row.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How about this? Please see the sample.
'11:33', '12:40', '17:06'

I want this data to be like this:
' ', '11:33', '12:40', '17:06'

Comment: What do you mean exactly? In the print for `res`, we have the row at index `2` as: `[None, '11:33', '12:40', '17:06']`. If you want `['', '11:33', '12:40', '17:06']` here, simply add another line: `res.fillna('', inplace=True)` or `res.fillna(' ', inplace=True)` (you want an empty space there?).

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry about that. Yes, this is working. But my dic looks like this and I'm getting a different output:
dic = {'Employee ID':emp_id, 'Log Date':emp_logdate, 'Log Time':emp_logtime}
df = pd.DataFrame(dic).groupby(['Employee ID','Log Date']).agg({'Log Date':'first', 'Log Time': lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique())})['Log Time'].astype(str).str.split(', ', expand=True).reset_index()

Comment: In order for us to work with this, you will need to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of this particular `df`. I.e. supply some values for the variables `emp_id`, `emp_logdate`, and `emp_logtime`. We cannot know what's in them.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, this should do what you want.

First I create `times_df` to store the times initially

```
# putting times supplied into a list
times = ['7:20','11:50','12:49','17:20','7:02','11:36','12:59','11:33','12:40','17:06','11:38']

# converts 'times' list to a df
times_df = pd.DataFrame(times,columns=["Time"])
# changes from str to datetime
times_df["Time"] = pd.to_datetime(times_df["Time"])
# sorts values, not really necessary, just to make it look nicer
times_df = times_df.sort_values("Time").reset_index(drop=True)
times_df
```

giving `times_df`

```
                  Time
0  2022-09-13 07:02:00
1  2022-09-13 07:20:00
2  2022-09-13 11:33:00
3  2022-09-13 11:36:00
4  2022-09-13 11:38:00
5  2022-09-13 11:50:00
6  2022-09-13 12:40:00
7  2022-09-13 12:49:00
8  2022-09-13 12:59:00
9  2022-09-13 17:06:00
10 2022-09-13 17:20:00
```

Next we have to take `times_df` and split it out into columns

```
times_groups = [(7,"AM In"),(11,"AM Out"),(12,"PM In"),(17,"PM Out")]

# create empty dataframe for result
out_df = pd.DataFrame()
for hour,name in times_groups:
    # selects the rows of times_df that match the hour that this group contains
    group = times_df[times_df["Time"].dt.hour == hour][["Time"]]
    # ranmes the column and resets index
    group = group.rename(columns={"Time":name}).reset_index(drop=True)
    # turns into series and converts data from datetime to time
    group = group[name].dt.time
    # appends column to end of out_df
    out_df = pd.concat([out_df,group],axis=1)
out_df
```

giving `out_df`

```
      AM In    AM Out     PM In    PM Out
0  07:02:00  11:33:00  12:40:00  17:06:00
1  07:20:00  11:36:00  12:49:00  17:20:00
2       NaN  11:38:00  12:59:00       NaN
3       NaN  11:50:00       NaN       NaN
```

This could also be easily amended to account for multiple hour in each group, e.g. 7a.m. & 8a.m. going into column "AM In".

Comment: 1/2
I have this dataframe:

          ID    Log Date      Log Time
0         2221  2022/08/01    07:11
1         2221  2022/08/01    11:03
2         2221  2022/08/01    17:05
3         2222  2022/08/01    11:36
4         2222  2022/08/01    18:34
5         2221  2022/08/02    06:56
6         2221  2022/08/02    17:14
7         2222  2022/08/02    07:14
8         2222  2022/08/02    12:55
9         2222  2022/08/02    18:12

Comment: 2/2
and I want to group this by ID and Log Date. So that it will result into 1 row of log time per date. And the time will join each other but it will find its proper palce for example log time from 6 to 7 will go on column 0, 11 to 12 is on column 1, 12 to 1 is on column 2 and 17 to 18 is on column 3.

          ID    Log Date      0      1      2     3
0         2221  2022/08/01    07:11  11:03  None  17:05
1         2222  2022/08/01    None   11:36  None  18:34
2         2221  2022/08/02    06:56  None   None  17:14
3         2222  2022/08/02    07:14  None   12:55 18:12